# Why isn't my question reopened?

Tags: support, specific-question, reopen-closed

From the help center:

> Questions that are edited within five days of being put on hold are automatically added to a reopening queue for community review. Questions that are not reopened within five days will change from [on hold] to [closed].

Here is my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20745864/how-to-unset-a-button)
As I edited it I see that it is not reopened as it should. Nor the question is put as active so it's not possible to review my question. What should I do to reopen it?

Comment: there are two reopen votes already, however

Comment: @JanDvorak Oh how can I see these votes?

Comment: As the question owner, you need 125 reputation

Comment: @JanDvorak: No, 250.

Comment: oops, sorry ...

Comment: It doesn't tell you that it should be reopened. It tells you it will be added to review queue where it has a chance to be reopened. If your edit doesn't raise the question quality to the needed level it will not get reopened. The good news is that you can edit it as many times as you need to.

Comment: @KateGregory except it gets converted to a CW at ten edits, and angers everybody sooner than that.

Comment: @JanDvorak any suggestions what point(s) should I clarify in my question.

Comment: @user689 I believe people would like to see your attempt. It helps to assess your level of knowledge. Also, rubberducking is a potent debugging practice.

Comment: @JanDvorak in that case the question should be closed for another reason.

Comment: @user689 it's not possible to change the close reason without reopening, and it's not worth reopening in order to close again

Comment: @JanDvorak ok thanks. I'll try as much as I can.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> why isn't my question reopened?

Because three users felt that it should remain closed:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/3649017

Comment: any speculation as to why?

Comment: @JanDvorak Presumably they were unclear what he was asking.  He should clarify his specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what he needs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though I don't know what is `unclear` in my question.

Comment: I failed an audit this way just yesterday... it's unclear to me how the question hadn't got any unclear votes despite having got a clarification request from a high-rep.

Answer (score 3):

> What should I do to reopen it?

Nothing. Your question is now pending in the Reopen queue (for review by members with 3k+ reputation), and if 5 members vote to reopen, your question will be reopened.

Comment: "edited 40 mins ago". The reopen queue is not that large.