# Does review activity appear in a question's timeline? If not it should

Tags: feature-request, review, timeline

It would be nice to be able to answer [*"Why isn't my question reopened?"*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213340/why-isnt-my-question-reopened) by refering to the [post's timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20745864/timeline) and seeing that reviews *have* occurred (and what the outcome has been).

Comment: That would be handy. It's in the mod-only timeline, of course - but that doesn't help unless you're a mod. (yes folks, there *is* a mod timeline - not to give too much away, but Atwood loses an arm in it)

Comment: Ah...so the answer is "Sorta". Perhaps the "what the results have been bit should be anonymized in the non-mod view.

Comment: Eh; just shove a link in there only after the review has completed. At that point, it's all public anway.